# How can I handle 403s with XML.load in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I'm writing a [Scala client to interface with Amazon's RESTful Product API](https://github.com/keplar/scalapac). To return the XML for a given request I'm using:

```
XML.load(uri)
```

This is working fine, except that sometimes when Amazon doesn't like e.g. the Signature embedded in `uri` and so it returns a 403 (along with a valid XML error report). Unfortunately this 403 throws an exception within `XML.load`:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://...
```

Ideally I'd like a way of flagging up the exception but returning the error XML anyway. Is there a simple way of doing this with `XML.load` I'm missing, or will I need to break it down into a two-stage get-then-load process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML.load(URL) makes use of Java's java.net.URL.openStream(), which is throwing the IOException in a way that doesn't give you any access to the "Error Stream"

So, you can make a more long-winded sequence of calls to get an InputStream, and then you can XML.load this resulting InputStream.

Use URL.openConnection() (instead of URL.openStream), and then call HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() from within a try block.
Then in your catch block, call HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream().

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29

Now you can call XML.load(InputStream) on the resulting InputStream.

Hope that's enough to set you on your way.

Comment: Many thanks for the guidance - I'm implementing it exactly how you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

In http dispatch (http://dispatch.databinder.net/About) this is doable like this:

```
import dispatch.Http._
import dispatch.{StatusCode, Http}
import xml.XML

try {
  Http("http://localhost/notthere" <> println)
} catch {
  case StatusCode(404, data) =>
    println(XML.loadString(data))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I hadn't heard of Scala Dispatch, looks interesting

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I ended up writing, many thanks for all the guidance above. (If anything in the below could be improved/made more idiomatic, do please let me know):

```
val url = new URL("http://ecs.amazonaws...")

val connection = url.openConnection() match {
  case x: HttpURLConnection => x
  case _ => throw new ClassCastException
}

val responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

val data = try {
  connection.getInputStream()
} catch {
  case e => connection.getErrorStream()
}

val xml = XML.load(data)
return (responseCode, xml)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this level of control you may use [ConstructingParser](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/xml/parsing/ConstructingParser.html). An example is included in that link. You obtain the raw `Source` and construct XML from it in two distinct steps using this technique.

Comment: Helpful example, thanks - am borrowing that PrettyPrinter code for a debug() method in my API...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which needs to add scalaj to project.

Step1: add scalaj to build.sbt (my scala version is 2.11.7 , but it still said my scala version was updated by one of libraray dependcies. so i add ivyscala to force update)

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "1.1.4"

ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
```

Step2: import library to code

```
import scalaj.http.Http
import scala.xml.XML
```

Step3: use http body to get rid of 403; add these codes to exception part when you get 403 exception.

```
val response = Http(your_url)
val responseExecute = response.execute()
val responseBody = responseExecute.body.toString
val xml = XML.loadString(responseBody)
```